# Analog of setPreviewCallbackWithBuffer in CameraX or android.hardware.camera2

Tags: android, android-camera, android-camera2, android-camerax

Is there a method similar to setPreviewCallbackWithBuffer in function in CameraX or android.hardware.camera2? This method was deprecated along with android.hardware.camera. Essentially I want to set a callback to the camera feed that presumes getting the image as a buffer. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Essentially, both **camera2** and **CameraX** work in a manner that is comparable to `setPreviewCallbackWithBuffer()`. You don't need to use some special methods to avoid memory allocations while capturing preview.